# Wordpress in subdirectory using wrong path for enqueing scripts

Tags: wordpress, wp-enqueue-scripts

I have been searching for a while but I haven't really seen anyone talk about this or found solutions.
At least nothing other then some hacks to help out from the functions.php

For a WordPress install at work I had to move the install into its own folder.
I used the guide here: https://wordpress.org/support/article/giving-wordpress-its-own-directory/#method-ii-with-url-change

Everything is working great and the folder structure is as expected:

```
- /
|-- Wordpress
|-- wp-content
  |-- themes
    |-- WebsiteTheme
```

So no worries there.
The functions.php has, for the moment, the following 2 lines in the wp-config.php

```
define( 'WP_HOME', 'https://dev.website.nl/' );
define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'https://dev.website.nl/wordpress' );
```

All in accordance with the guide from the official WordPress website.
But here is where things go weird.
When I try to Enqueue a script like this

```
$path = '/wp-content/themes/website/js/app.js';
wp_register_script('someName-'.$entry, $path, [], false, true);        
wp_enqueue_script('someName-'.$entry);
```

the path eventually is set as

```
/wordpress/wp-content/themes/website/js/app.js
```

which of course won't work.
It looks like the path is pre-fixed with the SITEURL instead of the HOME url.

Currently I am using a filter that hooks into the **script_loader_tag** and str_replace the "/wordpress" part out of the path if a conditional statement is true based on the name I gave the script.
But as I just followed the WordPress guide set this up, I thought this would not be an issue.
Any idea if I am missing something here?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The second parameter of `wp_register_script()` accepts `$src` as *the full URL of the script* **OR** *the path of the script **relative to the WordPress root directory***.

To prevent this issue caused by the latter default, you'd probably be better off passing the full URL.
I think you can do so by prepending `get_template_directory_uri()` or `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()`.

E.g.:

```
$path = '/js/app.js';
wp_register_script('someName-'.$entry, get_template_directory_uri() . $path, [], false, true);
```